# Will my CPU BottleNeck if I add a 1050 2GB

Tags: graphics-card

I had a question. I am searching for a powerful graphics card but my CPU is very weak to handle the GTX 1050 2 GB (Non-Ti). BTW the CPU is an Intel Core 2 Duo E8400 3.0 GHz. Will it bottleneck my CPU? Can it handle the graphics card?

Comment: Yes it will create a bottleneck,.

Comment: Your processor is indeed a huge bottlekneck.  Any program that requries a GTX 750 Ti+ is going to be severalty limited by your processor, almost to the point, where I doubt it will even run.

Answer (score 2):

> Can it handle the graphics card?

Yes; The power requirements for a stock GTX 750 Ti is only 75 W with a recommendation of a 300 W PSU.  The power requirements are nearly identical to that of the [GTX 750 Ti](https://www.geforce.com/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-gtx-750-ti/specifications).

> - Graphics Card Power (W) - 75 W
> - Minimum System Power Requirement (W) - 300 W

> Will it bottleneck my CPU?

Yes;  It will be severely bottlenecked by your 10-year-old CPU.

> Can it handle the graphics card?

While the [Intel Core 2 Duo E8400](https://ark.intel.com/products/33910/Intel-Core2-Duo-Processor-E8400-6M-Cache-3_00-GHz-1333-MHz-FSB) has a TDP of only **65 W**.  While I wouldn't suggest you use a cheap PSU, it would only be a suggestion not to use a cheap generic PSU, and it's only an opinion due to the many bad experiences I had with generic parts.

If you are installing a GTX 1050 into your system, in order to run applications that require it, you should first verify your processor meets the requirements of those applications.  Your processor is more than a decade old.

[Specifications](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/products/10series/geforce-gtx-1050/)